# Rename every file in directory tree C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, directory

I have a directory tree and want to rename every file and sub directory. In each directory the files and sub directories need to be renamed to numbers starting from one. Example:

Original directory tree:

```
Root
- Cooldir
   - anotherdir
     - file.txt
   - file.png
- Randomdir
   - secondfile.png
- name.txt
```

What i want it to look like.

```
Root
- 1
  - 1
    - 1
  - 2
- 2
  - 1
- 3
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you've tried and what problems you're hitting?

Answer (score 0):

A quick example could be the following:

```
void Recursive(string path)
{
    var exps = Enumerable
        .Union(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Select(o => new ExplorerInfo
        {
            Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(o),
            Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(o),
            Ext = Path.GetExtension(o),
            IsDir = false
        }), Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).Select(o => new ExplorerInfo
        {
            Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(o),
            Name = Path.GetFileName(o),
            IsDir = true
        })
        .OrderBy(n => Path.GetFileName(n.Name)));

    var i = 0;
    foreach (var exp in exps)
    {
        if (exp.IsDir)
        {
            Recursive(exp.Path + "\\" + exp.Name);
            Directory.Move(exp.Path + "\\" + exp.Name, exp.Path + $"/{++i}{exp.Ext}");
        }
        else
        {
            File.Move(exp.Path + "\\" + exp.Name + exp.Ext, exp.Path + $"/{++i}{exp.Ext}");
        }
    }
}
```

ExplorerInfo class:

```
public class ExplorerInfo
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ext { get; set; }
    public bool IsDir { get; set; }
}
```

Next time, add an example of your code to make the question clearer and to show that you actually tried to develop the application.